# filterContentForSearchText for multiple properties of an object simultaneously

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uisearchbar

I would like a user to be able to search through a table view of Shakespearean monologues to find the one they need most.

For example, there is a character named Helena in "All's Well That Ends Well", but there's another character named Helena in "A Midsummer Night's Dream". I'd like for the user to be able to input the name of the character and the name of the play in the same search bar to turn up their desired results

For example: the search query "helena midsummer" should only turn up monologues spoken by Helena in "A Midsummer Night's Dream".

Currently, upon searching "helena":
the results shows monologues from both "All's Well That End Well" and "A Midsummer Night's Dream".

But on searching "helena midsummer" or even just "helena ":
there are no results.

How can I allow filterContentForSearchText to ignore all white space while at the same time looking to see if any aspect of the search query matches any part of the monologue, whether it be the author name, text, title, character, etc.?

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
NSArray* words = [searchText componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet :[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
searchText = [words componentsJoinedByString:@""];

NSPredicate *p0 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title contains[cd] %@", searchText];
NSPredicate *p1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"authorFirst contains[cd] %@", searchText];
NSPredicate *p2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"authorLast contains[cd] %@", searchText];
NSPredicate *p3 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"text contains[cd] %@", searchText];
NSPredicate *p4 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"gender contains[cd] %@", searchText];
NSPredicate *p5 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tone contains[cd] %@", searchText];
NSPredicate *p6 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"period contains[cd] %@", searchText];
NSPredicate *p7 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"age contains[cd] %@", searchText];
NSPredicate *p8 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"length contains[cd] %@", searchText];
NSPredicate *p9 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"notes contains[cd] %@", searchText];
NSPredicate *p10 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tags contains[cd] %@", searchText];
NSPredicate *p11 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"character contains[cd] %@", searchText];

NSPredicate *predicateAll = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[p0, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, p11]];
searchResults = [monologuesArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicateAll];
}
```